# Something that should be added to a list in an if statment is not being added

Tags: php, database, if-statement, phpmyadmin

I am looping through a list of objects: however a couple of times (and always for the same ones) it will not work as expected.

I am trying to add the teacher object to the list if its ID does not match he Teacher ID of a previous Lesson in that time period (SubBlock/SB). The one particular teacher that it doesn't seem to like is a teacher who is free to teach all the lessons, out of the 6.

I am trying to get it to pick that teacher and it works on attempt 1,3,5 but not 2,4,6.

Here is the relevant function:

```
function getRelaventFreeTeachers(&$PossibleTeachers, $Teachers, $Lessons, $SB){
    foreach ($Teachers as $TeacherID){
    $Usability = 1;
    foreach ($Lessons as $Lesson){
        $LT = $Lesson->getLessonTeacher();
        $T = $TeacherID->getTID();
        $LSB = $Lesson->getBlock();
        if ($LT != $T){
            if ($LSB != $SB){
                $Usability = 1;
            }
        }else{
            $Usability = 0;
        }
     }
     if ($Usability == 1){
         array_push($PossibleTeachers, $TeacherID);
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What is te link with PHP My Admin in your question? What have you tryed this far at debugging your issue? Have you tryed dooing vardumps to see the progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not really very clear on the condition to add or not add a possible teacher, but some things seems wrong in the code:

- Once the variable `$Usability` is set to 0, your code does not prevent it from getting 1 again in a subsequent iteration of the inner loop. That does not look right. You should exit the inner loop as soon as you detect it is not OK.
- The case where you set `$Usability` to 1 is therefore not necessary: it already is 1 from the start, and when it gets 0 you exit. You wrote of a condition where the teacher should only be checked for a particular period. If I interpret that correctly then the code might need to look like this:

  ```
  if ($LT == $T && $LSB == $SB) { // Is the second condition indeed what you want?
      $Usability = 0;
      break;
  }
  ```